# Is there any way to identify the branch name used to create GIT TAG through the Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have developed the Jenkins pipeline to trigger after tagging Gitlab branches. In the Jenkins pipeline, I want to print the branch name that used to create TAG.
I tried through the environment variables which are set based on the GitLab JSON payload and unable to find a way.

[image: Try to print highlighted branch name in the Jenkins]

Comment: See `http[s]://<your Jenkins>/env-vars.html`: `GIT_BRANCH`, `GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH`.

Comment: @GeroldBroser thank you for the information.  I have replace the values in the url and tried, but I'm getting 404 error.